# How to prevent double execution of do_action statements

Tags: hooks

Is there any way to prevent double execution of do_action statements? For example, I have the following lines:

```
do_action('myhook1', 'myfunction1');
do_action('myhook2', 'myfunction2');
do_action('myhook3', 'myfunction3');
```

There are also other plugins that "might" be executing them.

Is there a built-in WordPress function or some means to prevent dual execution of do_action statements? What I need is that once they are activated or executed? Wordpress will simply ignore the other do_action statements.

Something like this condition:

```
if (!(already_executed)) {
//not executed
//execute the do_action lines

 do_action('myhook1', 'myfunction1');
 do_action('myhook2', 'myfunction2');
 do_action('myhook3', 'myfunction3');


}
```

Comment: Do you want to call a function with `do_acton()`? If so, you do it wrong. The syntax of `do_action()` is `do_action( [tag], [argument [, argument, argument]] )`. Maybe you mean `add_action( [tag], [function to call] )`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To check if someone already hooked into `myhook1`

```
if( 0 >= did_action( 'myhook1' ) )
  do_action( 'myhook1', 'myfunction1' );
```

If you want to check if the function `myfunction1` was already called (maybe by a simple function call), you have to set a 'marker'

```
function myfunction1 ( $some_args ) {

// with a simple global define (a bad solution)
  define( 'MYFUNCTION1_DONE', TRUE );

// or with the globals array (also a bad solution)

  $myfunction_calls = isset( $GLOBALS['myfunction_calls'] ) ?
    $GLOBALS['myfunction_calls'] : array();
  if( ! is_array( $myfunction_calls ) )
    $myfunction_calls = array();

  $myfunction_calls[__FUNCTION__] = TRUE;
  $GLOBALS['myfunction_calls'] = $myfunction_calls;

// or with database
//
// you have to reset the database entry everytime the script ends
// this is can be done by add_action( 'shutdown', 'reset_myfunctioncalls_db_entry' );
// or in a class with a __destruct() method
  $myfunction_calls = get_option( 'myfunction_calls', TRUE );
  if( ! is_array( $myfunction_calls ) )
    $myfunction_calls = array();

  $myfunction_calls[__FUNCTION__] = TRUE;
  upodate_option( 'myfunction_calls', $myfunctions );

[... some other code ...]
}
```

Before you call `do_action()`, you can check if the function was already called

```
if( ! defined( 'MYFUNCTION1_DONE' ) || TRUE !== MYFUNCTION1_DONE )
  do_action( 'myhook1', 'myfunction1' );

// or
$myfunction_calls = isset( $GLOBALS['myfunction_calls'] ) ?
  $GLOBALS['myfunction_calls'] : array();

if( ! isset( $myfunction_calls['myfunction1'] ) || TRUE !== $myfunction_calls['myfunction1'] )
  do_action( 'myhook1', 'myfunction1' );

// or
$myfunction_calls = get_option( 'myfunction_calls', TRUE );

if( ! isset( $myfunction_calls['myfunction1'] ) || TRUE !== $myfunction_calls['myfunction1'] )
  do_action( 'myhook1', 'myfunction1' );
```

Comment: thanks Ralf, does Wordpress core ignore the other do_action if the same hook is already executed? For example this statement occurred twice do_action( mytag, myargument )

Comment: If you have something like this `do_action( 'foo', 'a string as argument' ); [...] do_action( 'foo', 'another string as argument' );` then the hook will be executed twice. Simply don't use the same tag (hook) more than once.

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways:

1. Pass all the parameters at once:

   ```
   do_action( 'myhook1', 'myfunction1', 'myfunction2', 'myfunction3' );
   // or
   do_action( 'myhook1', array ( 'myfunction1', 'myfunction2', 'myfunction3' ) );
   ```
2. Create custom actions with the parameter as part of the name (if it is a scalar):

   ```
   do_action( 'myhook1_myfunction1' );
   do_action( 'myhook1_myfunction2' );
   do_action( 'myhook1_myfunction3' );
   ```

Note the second parameter of `do_action()` is **not** a function, it is a string. So, when somebody else is using that hook with `add_action()` no function will be called twice unless you are using exact same hook two times on a page.

Comment: If someone else hooked into `myhook1`, then the function(s) will be called( executed) a second time, or am I wrong? The question was how to prevent a second call of the functions, if I didn't missunderstood the question.

Comment: @Ralf912 No, the number of registered callbacks for a hook is almost unlimited. Using the same hook does not mean the same function will be executed.

Comment: I think he mean `add_action` and not `do_action`, because `'myfunction1'` is a bit wired argument.